PySimpleGUI. Кнопки
Как сделать так, чтобы функция работала после нажатия кнопки, а не во время нажатия.
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
def da():
    text_elem = window['-text-']
    button_elem1 = window['камень']
    button_elem1.update(visible=False)
    text_elem.update('1...')
    time.sleep(1)
    text_elem.update('2...')
    time.sleep(1)
    text_elem.update('3...')
layout=[  [sg.Text('Выберите', key='-text-')],
          [sg.Button('Камень', size=(20,10), key='камень')]]
window = sg.Window('Камень Ножницы Бумага', layout, size=(550,250))
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'камень':
        da()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()

Я бы хотел, чтобы после нажатия убиралась кнопка, а потом появлялись по очереди "1...", "2...", "3...". Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку, у меня 5 секунд анимация нажатой кнопки и сразу "3..."
